# Ubuntu does not detect my WLan signal after some distance far (like after 1 metre)

Tags: wireless

Ubuntu does not detect my WLan signal after some distance far (like after 1 metre).
here are the details of pc. Right now I am connected to mobile hotspot which is kept at very close distance( around 0.1 metres.) I

```
##### lsmod #############################

rtl8723be              98304  0
btcoexist             135168  1 rtl8723be
rtl8723_common         24576  1 rtl8723be
rtl_pci                32768  1 rtl8723be
rtlwifi                77824  4 rtl_pci,rtl8723be,btcoexist,rtl8723_common
mac80211              778240  3 rtl_pci,rtl8723be,rtlwifi
cfg80211              622592  2 rtlwifi,mac80211
hp_wmi                 16384  0
sparse_keymap          16384  1 hp_wmi
intel_wmi_thunderbolt    16384  0
wmi_bmof               16384  0
wmi                    24576  3 hp_wmi,intel_wmi_thunderbolt,wmi_bmof

##### iwconfig ##########################

enp1s0    no wireless extensions.

lo        no wireless extensions.

wlo1      IEEE 802.11  ESSID:"Realme 1"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.422 GHz  Access Point: <MAC 'Realme 1' [AC1]>   
          Bit Rate=72.2 Mb/s   Tx-Power=20 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr=2347 B   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:on
          Link Quality=36/70  Signal level=-74 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:440   Missed beacon:0
```

Comment: You might find an answer here if you search for hp rtl8723be

Comment: I have tried that solution but it does not work for me.

Comment: nothing happened I installed all the deb packages ,it was written done, But still the wifi range remains the same

Comment: Have you tried lfingers github rtlwifi-new?

Comment: they were asking to install kernel headers in the repository, is it necessary? what is it used for?

Comment: on this "Wifi signal strength weak on Ubuntu 18.04 with rtl8723be" (marked above link ) it gets installed done is written but still no improvement ,any reason?

Comment: thanks now it is working I reinstalled the realtek drivers and then used the lfingers repo